# Flexible timeout mechanism in JBoss Netty?

Tags: java, nio, netty

I am considering moving my Java NIO implementation over to [JBoss Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) as it provides a much cleaner model than I have implemented. The implementation manages a number of client connections to components over TCP using a proprietary protocol.

One aspect of my implementation, that I cannot see in Netty, is the ability to set arbitrary timeouts, which:

1. Wait for some data to be read from the Component.  I know that Netty has a `ReadTimeoutHandler` but can the timeout value be changed/turned off easily by the Component as it moves through the state machine?
2. Wait for time to elapse so that I can reconnect to the Component (to give the Component time to be restarted after a disconnect).  This is entirely unrelated to communication and is a simple timeout, however I'd like the timeout 'event/exception' to be presented to the handler class in the same manner as other communication-related timeouts.

Can this timeout mechanism be accomplished using Netty?

**Conclusion**: Given I would need to implement a timeout mechanism, which would run within the its own thread, I am not going to convert to using Netty after all.

Comment: What kind of channel you are implementing, server or client?

Comment: You mean "handle", not "handler"...

Comment: @someguy: No I'm using the term Handler for the class that 'represents' the component I'm communicating with. @secmask: They are client connections to multiple components.

Comment: Yes, it's usually called the "handle". A "handler", on the other hand, 'is an asynchronous callback subroutine that handles inputs received in a program' (wikipedia).

Comment: @someguy: Well a handle is a resource identifier and it's not that.  I'm using it in its generic sense, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [ChannelConfig](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelConfig.html). The method [setConnectTimeoutMillis(int)](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelConfig.html#setConnectTimeoutMillis%28int%29) sets the timeout in milliseconds. You can invoke this method via a [Bootstrap](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap.html) instance by calling [setOption(String, Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelConfig.html#setOption%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%29). The `name` would be "connectTimeoutMillis" and the `value` would be the desired timeout in milliseconds.

The following snippet shows how to set the connect timeout to 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds).

```
ClientBootstrap bootstrap... // bootstrap instance
bootstrap.setOption("connectTimeoutMillis", 5000);
```

Comment: Many thanks - however (and I think I wasn't clear here) - I use timeout value to throttle the reconnect.  The scenario is that the connection goes down and I want to give the component a chance to be restarted before connecting.  Will the method you describe satisfy that condition?

Comment: @trojanfoe In that case, you'll have to implement something like that yourself, as far as I know. As for the first part of your new question, I think you would have to use a different `ReadTimeoutHandler`. I guess you would have a different instance for each "state".

Comment: OK that makes sense, thanks.  Yes the timeout value changes for each state.